# How is the acceleration faster than the speed of light?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, dimensional-analysis, faster-than-light

The acceleration of a particle in an electric field given to me by a calculator is 175881998679 m/s squared - isnt that faster than light? How?

Comment: Please share some of the context of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Something could have that acceleration for 1 nanosecond and not exceed c.

Comment: Possibly @AdrianHoward.

Comment: @Jonas I used the equation a=qE/m and the electron's charge is -1.602176634E-19 kg, the mass is 9.1093837015E-31 C. The electric field is 1 N/C.

Comment: It could be a typing error .

Comment: The calculator actually gave me -175881998679 - the same but negative, however since acceleration is a vector, it is positive in the opposite direction, so it doesn't make a difference. Just if this changes anything

Comment: Acceleration is not velocity.  You are confusing the two.

Answer (score 2):

Acceleration and speed a fundamentally different things.  Speed is the change in position over time.  Acceleration is the change in speed over time.  Relativity limits speed not acceleration.

One hint that this was based on confusion were the units.  Speed would have been $m/s$.  You correctly showed units of acceleration in $m/s^2$.

Comment: My electron has acceleration 175881998679m/s squared, in an electric field with a potential difference of 5v - is this realistic or have I gone wrong?

Comment: You asked if it's faster than the speed of light, and I answered that.  If you're now asking if that's a reasonable acceleration, that's a different question that would require some context.

Comment: I used the equation a=qE/m and the electron's charge is -1.602176634E-19 kg, the mass is 9.1093837015E-31 C. The electric field is 1 N/C if that helps

Comment: Looks like you swapped charge and mass?

Comment: I tried again and got -0.9999999708 - more realistic?